# C++ Verifying User Input as Char or String

Tags: c++, loops

I am kind of new to C++, but I know Java. I have been given an assignment in which the program asks for an input "Active Military (Y/N): " and makes a decision based on the input. I am trying to prevent the program form getting confused by verifying the input. I am currently using spaghetti code because I cannot figure it out. Please don't judge. I am not proud of it either.

```
lable1:
cout << "Active Military (Y/N): ";
cin  >> strMilitary;

//Check for valid input
if(strMilitary == "Y")
{
    goto lable2;
}
if(strCounty == "N")
{
    goto lable2;
}

cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
goto lable1;

//Continue
lable2:

lable3:
cout << "Mecklenburg or Cabarrus (C/M): ";
cin  >> strCounty;

//Check for valid input
if(strCounty == "C")
{
    goto lable4;
}
if(strCounty == "M")
{
    goto lable4;
}

cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
goto lable3;

//Continue
lable4:
```

Is there any way I could use a while loop? I would really like to streamline this. As I said, I am not proud of its current state.

Comment: you are still using goto?

Comment: So... you used `goto` a lot in Java? Really, while there are many differences between the two languages, the basic flow structures are pretty much the same (branching, looping, etc.)

Comment: @crashmstr He said he knew Java, not that he knew programming.  Just knowing a language is only the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not using goto statements.

Here is how to get the input for the military using a while loop:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()  
{   
  char military = '\0'; // any initial value that's not Y or N
  while(military != 'Y' && military != 'N') {
    cout << "Active Military (Y/N): ";
    cin >> military;
  }

  cout << "You have entered: " << military << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` so you can handle both upper and lower case with one `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to use char variables instead of strings (since you're only using characters)

Following code will have a similar effect

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char military = '\0', county = '\0';

  while(1)
  {
    cout << "Active Military (Y/N): ";
    cin  >> military; 
    if( military == 'Y' || military == 'N' ) 
    {
      // maybe call a method to do something, depending on the input         
      break; 
    }
    cout << "Invalid Input!!";
  }     

  while(1)
  {
    cout << "Mecklenburg or Cabarrus (C/M): ";
    cin  >> county; 
    if( military == 'M' || military == 'C' ) 
    {
      // call a method to do something, depending on the input         
      break; 
    }
    cout << "Invalid Input!!";
  }      

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your code will fail if the User enters 'y' or 'n' to the first prompt and similarly, 'c' or 'm', for the second prompt.  Please read up on `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.